# Conditional compiler flag to detect storyboard in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard

How can you detect if you are in storyboard mode using conditional compiling?

Background: I want to display a static image instead of dynamic one for the storyboard view. I stumbled over an article on how to do that a while ago (so I know it's possible) but I can't find that anymore.

It's something similar to this:

```
#if storyboard
 statements
#else
 statements
#endif
```

Any advice?

Comment: Do you mean `init(coder:)`?

Comment: No, I mean conditional compiling. I need to execute completely different code while in the storyboard.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "while in the storyboard". A storyboard is something which causes controllers and views to be loaded. They don't run "in" the storyboard per se. Even if they did, this wouldn't be a compile-time condition.

Comment: Yes, they do. It will initialize all variables. You can easily test by adding some logging classes that output to windows outside of XCode.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. You're asking about `@IBDesignable`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer with TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER solved my problem perfectly. No more crashes with interface builder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER` or `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`, as described [here](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/).